# Intent not opening the next activity from project library I imported

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries, android-manifest, manifest

I am implementing this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHUGtlEaXqs in my project.
At the end of the tutorial, I should be able to open my MainActivity from the library imported.
However, I couldnt open it after hitting the button.
I think its because I have two android manifest files.
One from my project, another from the library.
So how do I sync it together?

Also the output that I have is that, after I hit the open face button, it is actually opening the same activity.
I think I put intent correctly in my button OnClickListener.

```
package com.example.cubacuba;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.samples.ui.MainActivityFace;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button openface = findViewById(R.id.button);
    openface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
    MainActivityFace.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
}
}
```

This is the output I'm having. Instead of showing the library's MainActivityFace after hitting the Open Face button, the app is still showing the same activity.

[image: First Page]
[image: Second Page]

This is my manifest file of my project where I want to go from my MainActivity to the library's MainActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.cubacuba">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Cubacuba"
    tools:replace="android:theme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity
    android:name="com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.samples.ui.MainActivity"

        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>



</application>

</manifest>
```

This is the manifest of the library I imported into my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.samples" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".helper.SampleApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:targetApi="donut">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivityFace"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />



    <activity
        android:name=".ui.DetectionActivity"
        android:label="@string/detection"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivityFace"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.MainActivityFace" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SelectImageActivity"
        android:label="@string/select_an_image"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

My gradle file for my project :

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cubacuba"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation project(':face')
}
```

The gradle file for the project's library I imported :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

// Include local lib mostly for debug purpose.
// implementation project(':lib')

// Use the following line to include client library for Face API from Maven 
Central Repository
implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.4.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Comment: Can you add the other project's and your build.gradle?

Comment: Sure @Sarah Check the edited question

Comment: I don't see a MainActivityFace activity in Library's manifest file

Comment: I have to copy the same code activity into the library's manifest file? I tried but the MainActivity parent name couldnt be initialised. it gives error @Sarah

Comment: Check my updated entry for the library's manifest. After run the code I still get the same output @Sarah

Comment: No no. What I am saying is in your code in the line, **Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityFace.class)** , I don’t see this MainActivityFace in the library’s manifest. You should define it just like other activities  say SelectImageActivity

Comment: I did define it in the library's manifest. check my library manifest code up there. still the output is the same @Sarah

Answer (score 1):

Every Android Studio project must contain at least one Manifest file, but it’s also possible for a project to contain multiple Manifests, for example you might create different Manifests for each product flavor or build type.

Since your finished APK can only contain a single Manifest, Gradle will merge all of your Manifests during the build process, to create the single Manifest file that’s ultimately shipped with your application.

If your project contains multiple Manifests, then Android Studio’s merger tool will combine each file sequentially based on its priority, where the lowest priority Manifest gets merged into the next highest priority.

for more refer to this link : [https://www.androidauthority.com/androidmanifest-xml-992934/#:~:text=%20If%20your%20project%20contains%20multiple%20Manifest%20files,screenshot%29.%20This%20will%20open%20a%20%E2%80%9CMerged...%20More%20](https://www.androidauthority.com/androidmanifest-xml-992934/#:%7E:text=%20If%20your%20project%20contains%20multiple%20Manifest%20files,screenshot%29.%20This%20will%20open%20a%20%E2%80%9CMerged...%20More%20)